# multi column select2 with dynamic number of columns

Tags: html, jquery, multiple-columns, jquery-select2

I want to create multi column `select2` with dynmaic number of columns that is I will specify the number of columns as data attribute in select tag. (or any other way possible)

```
<select data-cols="2,6,4"> <!--notice data-cols-->
   <option value="1">1| employeeName1| HR</option>
   <option value="2">2| employeeName2| IT</option>
   <option value="3">3| employeeName3| HR</option>
</select>
```

and jquery code is

```
$('.multiSelect2').select2({   
        templateResult: function(data) {
            console.log($(data.element).length);//is zero //error here
            var dataCols = $(data.element).parents('select').data('cols');
            var cols = dataCols.split(',').map(Number); 
            var result = $('<div class="row"></div>');
            cols.forEach(function(col, index) {
                result.append('<div class="col-md-' + col + '">' + data.text.split('| ')[index] + '</div>');
            });
            return result;
        },
        templateSelection: function(data) {
            console.log($(data.element).length);
            var dataCols = $(data.element).parents('select').data('cols');
            var cols = dataCols.split(',').map(Number); 
            var result = $('<div class="row"></div>');
            cols.forEach(function(col, index) {
                result.append('<div class="col-md-' + col + '">' + data.text.split('| ')[index] + '</div>');
            });
            return result;
        }
    });
```

inside `templateResult` `data.element` is undefined
how can I fix this, or change the approach to make dynamic number of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if `data.element` exist

```
templateResult: function(data) {
  if(!data.element) return;
  ...
```